# How can I circumvent MitM attacks on hostile networks?

Tags: networking, security

I suspect my local network is not as secure as one might like; I believe its administrator may be trying to intercept and sniff my traffic.

Are there any ways to prevent Man-in-the-Middle attacks that somebody would have at network level? How do I go about keeping my passwords and data safe?

I'm new when it comes to networking, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And also looking at this logically, if what you say is correct and your traffic is being intercepted, then whoever is intercepting the traffic will be able to see you posting this here and getting answers about it. And as this site does not have an HTTPS connection, the intercepted data won't even be encrypted.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda `https://askubuntu.com/` works.

Comment: @Oli: How come that is not default? Anyway, I don't suspect that when the OP posted it that they used the HTTPS version of AskUbuntu.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda [Read this from Meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13643/why-isnt-askubuntu-com-secure)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The same applies for any network you do not trust completely:

- Only use TLS (that is to say, only use URLs that begin with `https://`)
- Don't accept *any* certificates that aren't globally trusted.
- [Remove certificate exceptions](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/937304) from your browser
- If in doubt, use another encrypted network layer like socks over SSH, or use a VPN to a safe network.

You could argue that we should all be doing these all the time anyway.

However, even with these in place, **if somebody has had physical access to your computer though, all bets are off**. They could add certificates and change certificate settings so your browser, VPN client, etc wouldn't know it was using an intercepted connection when your network proxy re-encrypted it.

Full-disk encryption can help there but I wouldn't put money on it being fool-proof.

Somebody completely paranoid might suggest only ever using a bootable USB stick, with Tor over VPN, but the same applies... If that stick leaves your side for more than a few minutes, it's worthless.

Comment: thank you for you quick answer.no nobody has had access to my computer, but does the browser (google chrome) connect automatically via secure connection or are there exeptions?

Comment: No.  But you can use an extension like [HTTPS Everywhere](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/https-everywhere/gcbommkclmclpchllfjekcdonpmejbdp?hl=en)

Comment: @this.foo: If you like the answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like the answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask